# subscript is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code I am trying to populate a detail view from a tableView but keep getting that NSIndexPath error. Without the 'if let indexPath' and [indexPath] it only returns the first section in the dictionary.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let wod = FilteredWodList[index]
    if segue.identifier == "showBenchmarkDetail" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? BenchmarkWODDetailView
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        {
        controller?.nameText = wod.name![indexPath.row]
        controller?.descriptionText = wod.description![indexPath.row]
        controller?.exerciseText = wod.exercise![indexPath.row]
        }
```

I have also tried it with the following extension which instead causes me to the error 'Cannot assign value of type Character to type String'.

```
extension String {
subscript (index: Int) -> Character {
    let charIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(index)
    return self[charIndex]
}

subscript (range: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex)
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.count)

    return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
 }
}
```

https://github.com/Brandon-316/WOD-Guide
Located in BenchmarkWODViewController.swift

Comment: How have your declared `FilteredWodList` and `index`, and what have you assigned to them?

Comment: https://github.com/Brandon-316/WOD-Guide

Comment: You'd better include relevant codes into your post as text. Not many readers would follow the link. And you should mention at least what class in your github contains your shown code.

Comment: wod name property it is not an array, it is a String,  `controller?.nameText = wod.name!` should work. The same applies for description and exercise properties.

Comment: @LeoDabus The problem is when I just  use that code it only returns the first item in the dictionary no matter what row is selected.

Comment: You need to update the index inside the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath before performSegueWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing other parts of your code in BenchmarkWODViewController.swift, you need to modify your `prepareForSegue` as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showBenchmarkDetail" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? BenchmarkWODDetailView
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        {
            //This should be consistent with your `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`.
            let wod = FilteredWodList[indexPath.row]
            controller?.nameText = wod.name ?? ""
            controller?.descriptionText = wod.description ?? ""
            controller?.exerciseText = wod.exercise ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Key points are already found in Leo Dabus's comments.

Comment: That was exactly the fix I was looking for. Works perfectly thanks a lot!